# Efficient memory allocation before iterative algorithm

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I'm trying to implement an algorithm (C++) which is basically structured in the following way:

1. Build data structures which include

   a) vector(double)

   b) vector(vector(double)) (representing a sparse matrix A, inner vector 
     sizes not known a priori and also not the same)
2. Run an iterative algorithm performing lots of calculations on those 
   structures

To make it efficient I would like to make sure that before part two starts the memory is optimally allocated, so if possible that the vectors stored in A are next to each other in the memory without any overhead or anything. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Based on what you describe you can use a single vector for all the data and a separate vector of pointers to rows. Though usually a sparse matrix is sparse in both directions, so this may not be enough.

Comment: `vector<vector<double>>` is not enough for representing a general sparse matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make the creation of the vector more efficient you could use `vector::reserve` which reduces reallocation if append data to the vectors.

The access to the vectors is always as efficient as possible. The data in a `std::vector` is saved contiguously. That means that for big amounts of data it is not relevant if the inner vector are allocated nect to each other or not, because it need the same number of dereferencings.

In general I would say the STL is pretty efficient, but except for functions like `reserve` you can not do much to optimize it.

If you need higher speed you have to use a data structure that is optimized for your use case.

Comment: Thanks, I see. So what about the following code:

vector(vector(double)) A;

A = build_A(); // Here I know the dimensions of every inner vector

vector(vector(double)) A_efficient;

A_efficient.reserve(A.size())

for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); ++i){

A_efficient[i].reserve(A[i].size())

for(int j = 0; j < A[i].size(); ++j) A_efficient[i].push_back(A[i][j])

}

Comment: Reserve only optimize the insertion of new elements to the vector. If you have already created A with all data you can use it without any performance issues. The reserve could be used to optimize the creation of the vector A.

Comment: This confuses me a bit. As I create A adding entries to the vectors is all over the place, sometimes I might add something to A[i], then to A[j],.. so thinking of the memory as a stack, how is it possible that A[i] is stored consecutively?

Comment: If you push data to an `std::vector` which has no capacity to save it, it will allocate more memory and copy the existing data to the new memory (in worst case).